# Combobox ItemsSource using old values from Settings file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to create a ComboBox and populate the values using Settings file. 
In the first attempt it works but when I try to change the values in Settings file, it is not reflected in the list of items in the ComboBox. 
Code Snippets for the same -

ComboBox xaml code -

```
                    <ComboBox Name="vGameMode"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings1.Default}, Path=Modes}"
                    SelectedIndex="1">
                    <!-- <ComboBoxItem Content="Personal"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Corporate"/> -->
                </ComboBox>
```

Values in Settings File -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="ABC" GeneratedClassName="Settings1">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="Themes" Type="System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Theme1&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Theme2&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Theme3&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="DefaultMaxScore" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">1000</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="DefaultTimeoutSeconds" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">300</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="LeaderboardDays" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">7</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="NumberOfTasks" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">3</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="CurrentModeIndex" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">0</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="DifficultyLevels" Type="System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Medium&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Hard&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="GameType" Type="System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Laser Maze&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Laser Buster&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Any idea what is wrong here? 
I am guessing it is cached somewhere but not sure where.

Comment: Did you recompile your project after editing the settings?

Comment: Try running the project from a different network. Use a mobile hotspot or another wifi. You will get the updated values most likely. I had the same caching issue

Comment: @michip96 - Yes. I did recompile multiple times. I also cleaned the project and rebuilt it atleast thrice.

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath - How does changing the network help? I am making changes and running the project locally. There is not network involvement whatsoever in the app.

Comment: ISP's use proxy servers to cache the data in their servers at the server level. Using a different network will eliminate that. Has worked for me

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath - I am not fetching the values from the Internet. Settings1.settings file is modified locally in my desktop.

Comment: Show your complete settings file please. I doubt the <ArrayOfString> is a valid root element for a settings file...

Comment: You are trying to bind to a property/setting in your settings called "Modes". Can you please point me to where in your settings file this "Modes" property/setting is located? ;)

Comment: Oh.. I deleted it actually. Sorry for that. BTW.. I am facing the same problem with "DifficultyLevels".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call Settings1.Default.Save() somewhere in there.  I forget that all the time.

Comment: I am not changing the values dynamically. I am directly modifying the Settings1.settings file.